# Multiple function signatures in externs rule

Tags: google-closure-compiler, webassembly

I am writing closure externs for WebAssembly.

For function `WebAssembly.instantiate`, it has 2 function signatures.

- `Promise<{module:WebAssembly.Module, instance:WebAssembly.Instance}>
  instantiate(BufferSource bytes [, importObject])`
- `Promise<WebAssembly.Instance> instantiate(moduleObject [, importObject])`

How to declare both rules in closure externs?

Reference:

https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md#webassemblyinstantiate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that argument and result are union of two different types.  See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler about how to specify types.

Here is a simple example of such a function:

```
/**
* @param {string|number} value
* @return {string|number}
*/
ambiguous = function(value) {
  if (typeof value == 'string') {
    return value+' is string';
  } else if (typeof value == 'number') {
    return value+1;
  } else throw new Error();
};
```

For your `WebAssembly.instantiate` function you will of course have more complex types than string and number.  I don't know how you would specify the Promise types, I don't recognize the syntax shown for those, and I doubt closure compiler will parse that as-is.  The extern then looks something like this (with bogus types for the Promises).

```
/**
@param (!BufferSource|!WebAssembly.Module) arg1 either a BufferSource or a module
@param Object= importObject  optional object to import
@return (!PromiseType1|!PromiseType2)
*/
WebAssembly.instantiate = function(arg1, importObject) {};
```

The `!` symbol is used to indicate a non-null object.  If these can be null then leave that out. The `=` symbol after `Object=` means it can be undefined.

When using the results of this function you will need to test what type of thing you got using `instanceof` or some other method. Otherwise the compiler only knows the result is one of the two possible types. If not using `instanceof`, you can use *type casting* to tell the compiler that you know what the type is, see end of that page referenced above.

An example of a function from closure-library that has a union type in both its argument and its result is [goog.array.find](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.array.html). The [source for goog.array.find](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/array/array.js#L496) is available. Note that the angle brackets `<>` are used for the template type feature of the compiler.